# How To Implement Progress bar when some function is working in my web Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp

One of the services it provides is that when the user clicks on a button a long running process will occur on the server. (Query database, write files, write logs, etc...) this process can take a few seconds or a few minutes.
*Problem*** How can I implement the service to update the client of its progress.

@PostMapping(value = "/convert", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public ZawGyi2UnicodeJsonRespone convert(@ModelAttribute @Valid ZawGyi2Unicode zg2un, BindingResult result)
throws IOException, ParseException {

```
    ZawGyi2UnicodeJsonRespone respone = new ZawGyi2UnicodeJsonRespone();
```

....

data.put("-",
new Object[] { data0, data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9, data10, data11,
data12, data13, data14, data15, data16, data17, data18, data19, data20, data21, data22,
data23, data24, data25, data26, data27, data28, data29, data30 ,cell31 });

```
            // Iterate over data and write to sheet
            Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();

            for (String key : keyset) {
                row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
                int cellnum = 0;
                for (Object obj : objArr) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                    cell.getStringCellValue().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                    if (obj instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                    } else if (obj instanceof Date) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                    } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        } try {
                
                //get befor "."
                String filename = filePath; 
                int iend = filename.indexOf(".");
                String subString="";
                if (iend != -1) {
                    subString = filename.substring(0, iend);
                }

                
                outPutPath = subString+"Output.xlsx";
                
                // Write the workbook in file system
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_PATH+outPutPath));
                //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(outPutPath));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        respone.setValidated(true);
        respone.setZg2un(zg2un);
    }
    return respone;
}
```

Comment: Add a "fake" loader. It will slowly load to leave a big amount of time for action to be done and when actinon completes, move progress bar to finish.

Comment: some excel file 100 row is very fast but 20000 excel row processing time going slow.

Comment: so i need dynamic progress bar...